# Pycharm not prompting for input

Tags: python-3.x

[code that i have written , it is working fine but not prompting to enter a input and not processing the code when i run this , i have tries to check for file configuration but it is also fine][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4abs.pngcode that i have written , it is working fine but not prompting to enter a input and not processing the code when i run this , i have tries to check for file configuration but it is also fine

Comment: You have to unindent your call to `guess`

Answer (score 0):

In python **you have to be careful with indentation**, since the `guess()` you call at the end is defined inside the function so it will not run as you wish. First, you must call the function from outside it.

In addition, you have indicated in the definition of the function `def guess(x)` that you must pass an argument, which you should also do. For example, this code is functional:

```
import random

def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1, x)
    guess = 0
    while guess != random_number:
        guess = int(input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}: '))
        if guess < random_number:
            print('Sorry, guess again. Too low.')
        elif guess > random_number:
            print('Sorry, guess again. Too high.')

    print(f'Yay, congrats. You have guessed the number {random_number} correctly!!')

guess(10)
```

As you can see, the function is called after being declared (at the same indentation level, i.e. outside of it) and, in addition, an argument is passed to it.